# Find a basis for the following linear space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S = \left\{A\in M_2(\mathbb{R}):A\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}A\right\}$ be a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$. Find a basis for $S$.

Here's what I did:

Let $ A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}\in S$ , $a_1,a_2,a_4,a_4 \in \mathbb{R}$ . I want $A\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}A$, $ A = \begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\0&a_1\end{bmatrix}$. That means that $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2=ka_1\\0&a_1\end{bmatrix} :a_1,k\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

So, a basis for $S$ is : $\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&k\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$? What am i missing?

Comment: A parameter for the leading diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix}$. Using the fact that $A\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}$A, we get the following:
\begin{align}
a&=d\\
c&=0.
\end{align}

And so, the set $S$ contains matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    0 & a 
  \end{bmatrix}$.

A basis for this set is $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2  \\ a_3 & a_4   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1  \\ 0 & 1   
\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_1+a_2  \\ a_3 & a_3+a_4   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1  \\ 0 & 1   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2  \\ a_3 & a_4   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+a_3 & a_2+a_4  \\ a_3 & a_4   \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Consider the leading diagonal $a_3=0$ , now the $(1,2)$ entry will be satisfied. The $(2,1)$ gives $a_1=a_4=j$. So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
j & k  \\ 0 & j  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
is a parameterisation of the space.